# How to configure timeout in mount cifs (smb)

Tags: timeout, mount, nfs, smb, cifs

The command i am using right now is:

```
mount -t cifs //192.168.0.1/g /mnt/network -o user=user,pass=pass,vers=3,domain
```

Now i have to configure timeout in it, by reading the documentation i have figured out "handletimeout" command option but it seems like its not working.

can anyone help me, how to configure timeout in "mount -t cifs" command?

REF:

- https://manpages.debian.org/testing/cifs-utils/mount.cifs.8.en.html
- https://www.mankier.com/8/mount.cifs